# wordpress page id to page name changing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a theme for wordpress. All is working well. I want to change the page id to page name in url. I changed selection from default to Post name. wordpress root has a `.htaccess` file and it contains the required code.

If I click on the menu item then the page is not displayed and it displays as "Not Fount,.. page was not fount on this server", only home page is displayed. If I select default in permalink then it is working and open well all pages.

I used wamp server, windows7. .htaccess file has required code. What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: Enable `mod_rewrite` in your apache configuration, restart your server and try again
Using wamp: Wamp tray icon > Apache > Modules > rewrite module and select it. If it still does not work, open the httpd.conf of your apache server and remove the `#` from the line : `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
`

Comment: Great. It is working well after selecting the rewrite module. Thank you very much. It was very helpful to me.